# RESTful service with TomEE and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, rest, java-ee-7, tomee-7

I followed the tutorial [here](http://jason.zwolak.org/technoblog/2013/06/restful-service-with-tomee-and-intellij-idea/)

And i can't get the example running for some reason... i'm getting 404 error on entering the url http://localhost:8080/greeting/ after running the service.

I'm using Intellji EE 14 and TomEE 7.

Here is my code:

Greeter.java:

```
package org.mybiz;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("greeting")
public class Greeter {
    @GET
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi!!";
   }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

Comment: when you start the service , check the logs for all the exposed urls. Check if http://localhost:8080/greeting/  is there or not. Paste the logs in case you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check it is deployed in the logs (you should have the http://localhost:8080/greeting/)

If not their is maybe a compilation issue, if yes and you get an exception accessing the url it can be you access it with a mimetype not matching the defined one.

Try adding `@Consumes("text/plain")` or `@Consumes("text/html")`

Comment: Its compiles just fine  and no runtime execeptions, although localhost:8080/greeting/ is not apearing in the logs. I tried using @Consumes text and html no luck.

Comment: if you dont see it in the logs then it is not scanned, can be due to several things (i called it compilation issue which was probably a bad language shortcut). Can you validate the classes are in WEB-INF/classes in the deployed binary?